# Changes to Django Template is not reflecting

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-quiz

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz to use this project.
I am able to successfully use the project.
However, when I change the template (.html files) nothing changes. Even If I add or delete the entire content. I am not sure if I am missing something.
I checked in views.py and I cannot see any html renders. I am new to Django and finding it difficult to understand views.py and make any changes to the templates like questions or category. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Interestingly if I make any changes to my original base.html the css and styles are applied as well as any other changes in base.html

urls.py code

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$',
        view=QuizListView.as_view(),
        name='quiz_index'),

    url(r'^category/$',
        view=CategoriesListView.as_view(),
        name='quiz_category_list_all'),

    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name>[\w|\W-]+)/$',
        view=ViewQuizListByCategory.as_view(),
        name='quiz_category_list_matching'),

    url(r'^progress/$',
        view=QuizUserProgressView.as_view(),
        name='quiz_progress'),

    url(r'^marking/$',
        view=QuizMarkingList.as_view(),
        name='quiz_marking'),

    url(r'^marking/(?P<pk>[\d.]+)/$',
        view=QuizMarkingDetail.as_view(),
        name='quiz_marking_detail'),

    #  passes variable 'quiz_name' to quiz_take view
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        view=QuizDetailView.as_view(),
        name='quiz_start_page'),

    url(r'^(?P<quiz_name>[\w-]+)/take/$',
        view=QuizTake.as_view(),
        name='quiz_question'),
]
```

Views.py code

```
class QuizMarkerMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(permission_required('quiz.view_sittings'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(QuizMarkerMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class SittingFilterTitleMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(SittingFilterTitleMixin, self).get_queryset()
        quiz_filter = self.request.GET.get('quiz_filter')
        if quiz_filter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(quiz__title__icontains=quiz_filter)

        return queryset


class QuizListView(ListView):
    model = Quiz

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QuizListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(draft=False)


class QuizDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Quiz
    slug_field = 'url'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if self.object.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)


class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Category


class ViewQuizListByCategory(ListView):
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'view_quiz_category.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(
            Category,
            category=self.kwargs['category_name']
        )

        return super(ViewQuizListByCategory, self).\
            dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ViewQuizListByCategory, self)\
            .get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['category'] = self.category
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ViewQuizListByCategory, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(category=self.category, draft=False)


class QuizUserProgressView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'progress.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(QuizUserProgressView, self)\
            .dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizUserProgressView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        progress, c = Progress.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        context['cat_scores'] = progress.list_all_cat_scores
        context['exams'] = progress.show_exams()
        return context


class QuizMarkingList(QuizMarkerMixin, SittingFilterTitleMixin, ListView):
    model = Sitting

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QuizMarkingList, self).get_queryset()\
                                               .filter(complete=True)

        user_filter = self.request.GET.get('user_filter')
        if user_filter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user__username__icontains=user_filter)

        return queryset


class QuizMarkingDetail(QuizMarkerMixin, DetailView):
    model = Sitting

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sitting = self.get_object()

        q_to_toggle = request.POST.get('qid', None)
        if q_to_toggle:
            q = Question.objects.get_subclass(id=int(q_to_toggle))
            if int(q_to_toggle) in sitting.get_incorrect_questions:
                sitting.remove_incorrect_question(q)
            else:
                sitting.add_incorrect_question(q)

        return self.get(request)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizMarkingDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['questions'] =\
            context['sitting'].get_questions(with_answers=True)
        return context


class QuizTake(FormView):
    form_class = QuestionForm
    template_name = 'question.html'
    result_template_name = 'result.html'
    single_complete_template_name = 'single_complete.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
        if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        try:
            self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated()
        except TypeError:
            self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated

        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user,
                                                        self.quiz)
        else:
            self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()

        if self.sitting is False:
            return render(request, self.single_complete_template_name)

        return super(QuizTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.question = self.sitting.get_first_question()
            self.progress = self.sitting.progress()
        else:
            self.question = self.anon_next_question()
            self.progress = self.anon_sitting_progress()

        if self.question.__class__ is Essay_Question:
            form_class = EssayForm
        else:
            form_class = self.form_class

        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(QuizTake, self).get_form_kwargs()

        return dict(kwargs, question=self.question)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.form_valid_user(form)
            if self.sitting.get_first_question() is False:
                return self.final_result_user()
        else:
            self.form_valid_anon(form)
            if not self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]:
                return self.final_result_anon()

        self.request.POST = {}

        return super(QuizTake, self).get(self, self.request)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizTake, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question'] = self.question
        context['quiz'] = self.quiz
        if hasattr(self, 'previous'):
            context['previous'] = self.previous
        if hasattr(self, 'progress'):
            context['progress'] = self.progress
        return context

    def form_valid_user(self, form):
        progress, c = Progress.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        guess = form.cleaned_data['answers']
        is_correct = self.question.check_if_correct(guess)

        if is_correct is True:
            self.sitting.add_to_score(1)
            progress.update_score(self.question, 1, 1)
        else:
            self.sitting.add_incorrect_question(self.question)
            progress.update_score(self.question, 0, 1)

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
            self.previous = {'previous_answer': guess,
                             'previous_outcome': is_correct,
                             'previous_question': self.question,
                             'answers': self.question.get_answers(),
                             'question_type': {self.question
                                               .__class__.__name__: True}}
        else:
            self.previous = {}

        self.sitting.add_user_answer(self.question, guess)
        self.sitting.remove_first_question()

    def final_result_user(self):
        results = {
            'quiz': self.quiz,
            'score': self.sitting.get_current_score,
            'max_score': self.sitting.get_max_score,
            'percent': self.sitting.get_percent_correct,
            'sitting': self.sitting,
            'previous': self.previous,
        }

        self.sitting.mark_quiz_complete()

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end:
            results['questions'] =\
                self.sitting.get_questions(with_answers=True)
            results['incorrect_questions'] =\
                self.sitting.get_incorrect_questions

        if self.quiz.exam_paper is False:
            self.sitting.delete()

        return render(self.request, self.result_template_name, results)

    def anon_load_sitting(self):
        if self.quiz.single_attempt is True:
            return False

        if self.quiz.anon_q_list() in self.request.session:
            return self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]
        else:
            return self.new_anon_quiz_session()

    def new_anon_quiz_session(self):
        """
        Sets the session variables when starting a quiz for the first time
        as a non signed-in user
        """
        self.request.session.set_expiry(259200)  # expires after 3 days
        questions = self.quiz.get_questions()
        question_list = [question.id for question in questions]

        if self.quiz.random_order is True:
            random.shuffle(question_list)

        if self.quiz.max_questions and (self.quiz.max_questions
                                        < len(question_list)):
            question_list = question_list[:self.quiz.max_questions]

        # session score for anon users
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()] = 0

        # session list of questions
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()] = question_list

        # session list of question order and incorrect questions
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()] = dict(
            incorrect_questions=[],
            order=question_list,
        )

        return self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]

    def anon_next_question(self):
        next_question_id = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()][0]
        return Question.objects.get_subclass(id=next_question_id)

    def anon_sitting_progress(self):
        total = len(self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['order'])
        answered = total - len(self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()])
        return (answered, total)

    def form_valid_anon(self, form):
        guess = form.cleaned_data['answers']
        is_correct = self.question.check_if_correct(guess)

        if is_correct:
            self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()] += 1
            anon_session_score(self.request.session, 1, 1)
        else:
            anon_session_score(self.request.session, 0, 1)
            self.request\
                .session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['incorrect_questions']\
                .append(self.question.id)

        self.previous = {}
        if self.quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
            self.previous = {'previous_answer': guess,
                             'previous_outcome': is_correct,
                             'previous_question': self.question,
                             'answers': self.question.get_answers(),
                             'question_type': {self.question
                                               .__class__.__name__: True}}

        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()] =\
            self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()][1:]

    def final_result_anon(self):
        score = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()]
        q_order = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['order']
        max_score = len(q_order)
        percent = int(round((float(score) / max_score) * 100))
        session, session_possible = anon_session_score(self.request.session)
        if score is 0:
            score = "0"

        results = {
            'score': score,
            'max_score': max_score,
            'percent': percent,
            'session': session,
            'possible': session_possible
        }

        del self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end:
            results['questions'] = sorted(
                self.quiz.question_set.filter(id__in=q_order)
                                      .select_subclasses(),
                key=lambda q: q_order.index(q.id))

            results['incorrect_questions'] = (
                self.request
                    .session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['incorrect_questions'])

        else:
            results['previous'] = self.previous

        del self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]

        return render(self.request, 'result.html', results)


def anon_session_score(session, to_add=0, possible=0):
    """
    Returns the session score for non-signed in users.
    If number passed in then add this to the running total and
    return session score.

    examples:
        anon_session_score(1, 1) will add 1 out of a possible 1
        anon_session_score(0, 2) will add 0 out of a possible 2
        x, y = anon_session_score() will return the session score
                                    without modification

    Left this as an individual function for unit testing
    """
    if "session_score" not in session:
        session["session_score"], session["session_score_possible"] = 0, 0

    if possible > 0:
        session["session_score"] += to_add
        session["session_score_possible"] += possible

    return session["session_score"], session["session_score_possible"]
```

[image]
When I make changes to etbox/templates/base.html , my changes are reflected in all the Quiz Html(s).

Comment: Share some of the code, (*views, template, urls etc.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your links and templates should link up:

- You first create a url address in your apps directory folder in file called `urls.py`:

  ```
  """Defines the URL patterns for app created within django"""
  from django.conf.urls import url
  from . import views

  urlpatterns = [
     # Home page
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),#notice how I mention the function called index within the views.py file
     ...
  ]
  ```
- Then you add a function within the same folder as your `urls.py` that allows to carry information from your models and forms into your templates (but that is optional).

  ```
  def index(request):
     """Creating a homepage view"""
     return render(request, '#app_name/index.html')
  ```
- When creating an `.html` file remember that it's supposed to located in a specific location for django to read it. This is most likely your problem. Your `.html` file isn't in the right location for django to render it.
  This is the general file path from your main project directory for the `.html` file. *#main_directory/#django_app_directory/#templates/#django_app_name_folder/.html_file*
  . So basically the `.html` file has to be located in a folder called `templates` within the same directory as your `views.py` and `urls.py`. Inside the `templates` folder you make another folder that is called the same as your app name folder. Within this app name folder you can put your `.html` file.

Comment: An example of the file path would (your app_name = quiz, main_directory= project): project/quiz/templates/quiz/.html

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look at it and it seems in views.py that he's using just generic views, that's why he never calls the render function directly.

So, as you can see in urls.py, the home page is associated with QuizListView from views.py QuizListView inherits from django.views.generic.ListView

If you look at the documentation, you will see that the default template name for that is the name of the model you specify + '_list'

```
class QuizListView(ListView):
model = Quiz

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(QuizListView, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(draft=False)
```

This template is in this path: django_quiz/quiz/templates/quiz/quiz_list.html

Edit it and the changes should reflect in the browser when you refresh the page

Comment: I made changes to the quiz_list.html in the path mentioned and it doesn't change. Interestingly if I make any changes to my original base.html the css and styles are applied as well as any other changes in base.html